# Wildcard certificate with prefix

Tags: ssl, wildcard

I am wondering if it's possible to create a wildcard certificate with a prefix.

I know that `*.example.com` will cover anything at the first level (eg. `one.example.com`, `two.example.com`, `three-four.example.com`, etc), but will not cover `another.one.example.com` because that's 2 levels.

I need to have a wildcard certificate that recognizes a prefix; so it would be `www.*.example.com`.

That means, `www.one.example.com`, `www.two.example.com`, `www.three.example.com`, etc would all work correctly.

Is this possible, and is there a certificate provider that can do this?

Comment: Use a UCC certificate which protects _x_ hostnames. The bad part is that the list of hostnames is hardcoded in the certificate.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/830561/111679

Answer (score 10):

> I need to have a wildcard certificate that recognizes a prefix; so it would be `www.*.example.com`.
> That means, `www.one.example.com`, `www.two.example.com`, `www.three.example.com`, etc would all work correctly.

> Is this possible, and is there a certificate provider that can do this?

No. According to the rules of the CA browser forum, [RFC2818](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt) and [RFC6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125) only one wildcard is allowed and only in the leftmost label. Which means there is no `www.*.example.com` and no `*.*.example.com` either. You need instead to add all the domains you need in the subject alternative name part of the certificate, but you could have multiple entries and and you can use wildcards, i.e. `*.sub1.example.com`, `*.sub2.example.com` etc.

Such certificates with multiple wildcard names are common (look at the certificate for Facebook) which means there are certificate providers which offer these certificates. But they will cost more than others.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `.cnf`-file like the following, which you use with `openssl req -new -out example.com.csr -key example.com.key -config example.com.cnf`.
You can create the keyfile using

```
openssl genrsa -out example.com.key 4096
```

The `example.com.cnf` file:

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[req_distinguished_name]
commonName = example.com

[v3_req]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = example.com
DNS.2 = www.example.com
DNS.2 = *.example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe do you need to use SubjectAltName.

Take a look at: http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName