# WWW prefix results in non secure connection on IIS 8.5 (subdomain) after adding SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, iis

I was trying to get subdomain to have ssl connection.

https://subdomain.myfantasticwebsite.com - works fine
https://www.subdomain.myfantasticwebsite.com - loads up with browser notification that the connection is not secure.

I added 2 records to site bindings- both 
https type
one with www prefix
the other without prefix
both on port 443,

and certificate works well as per above (for without www prefix). Is there any other place/setting that could potentially cause this problem?

It is a subdomain - if it makes any difference.

Windows 2012 2 IIS 8.5

Comment: Make sure the certificate was issued for both `subdomain.myfantasticwebsite.com` AND `www.subdomain.myfantasticwebsite.com`.

Comment: Hi, I have checked and the certificate is both for www and non-www prefixes to subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

there are many types of SSL certificates cover.

One I have is wildcard that covers any subdomain. Not subdomain**s**.

Therefore https://*.myfantasticwebsite.com equals
https://www.myfantasticwebsite.com
and
https://subdomain.myfantastiwebsite.com

but not

https://www.subdomain.myfantasticwebsite.com as it would be https://*.*.myfantasticwebsite.com

which is a subdomain of a subdomain (although it is www prefix).

One way to solve it is to buy SAN certificate - most expensive.

Other way is to buy extra certificate for subdomain of subdomain - expensive.

Final way is to redirect traffic from www to non-www prefix... - free.

I find it poor that a wildcard certificate does not cover all subdomains (and subdomains of subdomains) to the left of the main address...

Poor implementation or great business idea...

More to read:

[Wildcard SSL with prefix](https://serverfault.com/questions/692215/wildcard-ssl-with-prefix)

[Wildcard SSL with prefix](https://serverfault.com/questions/692215/wildcard-ssl-with-prefix)

[Should a wildcard SSL certificate secure both the root domain as well as the sub-domains?](https://serverfault.com/questions/310530/should-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-secure-both-the-root-domain-as-well-as-the-sub)